# What is the view returned in the onLoadingComplete callback from ImageLoadingListener?

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I'm using the loadImage method from nostra13's excellent Android-Universal-Image-Loader image library and I'm wondering what view is returned in the onLoadingComplete callback of ImageLoadingListener. Here's the method:

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

I'm not specifying any view, so how can it return a view?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the Android-Universal-Image-Loader. However you could set a breakpoint in the callback and debug. There you can check what view it is.

Comment: It's null, obviously :) For `loadImage(...)` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `loadImage(...)` method then you'll get `view == null` in your callback.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ImageLoader class soruces here:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoader.java

```
public void loadImage(String uri, ImageSize targetImageSize, DisplayImageOptions options,
            ImageLoadingListener listener, ImageLoadingProgressListener progressListener) {
        checkConfiguration();
        if (targetImageSize == null) {
            targetImageSize = configuration.getMaxImageSize();
        }
        if (options == null) {
            options = configuration.defaultDisplayImageOptions;
        }

        NonViewAware imageAware = new NonViewAware(uri, targetImageSize, ViewScaleType.CROP);
        displayImage(uri, imageAware, options, listener, progressListener);
    }
```

So it will return new NonViewAware instance, which is probably not useful for you.

Comment: It returns `ImageViewAware.getWrappedView()` actually. Which is `null` for `loadImages(...)` case.